# Features importance with python's sklearn ExtraTreesClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Trying to apply sklearn ExtraTreesClassifier() for detecting the importances of the features in the dataset (new_y dataframe). So I select the values from the dataset (x) and the column names (y) and try to make a model:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

arrX=new_y.values
arrY=new_y.columns.values

model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(arrX,arrY)

model.feature_importances_
```

It gives me an error, like 'Number of labels=18 does not match number of samples=161389'
So what I'm doing wrong and how it should be done correctly?

Comment: When you get an error you're supposed to state on which line! anyway, this looks wrong: `arrY=new_y.columns.values` you're supposed to be passing the target values, not the column names, shouldn't it be `arrY = new_y.values` ?

Comment: so x and y will be identical?

Comment: Sorry there is an error in my last comment, you're supposed to pass the features as X and the target prediction column as Y, So whatever your features are pass this for X and usually the last column is the target prediction, see the docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html what you did was just pass your column names which is wrong you're supposed to pass an array which has the same number of rows as your array but is a single column

Comment: yep, I got it) thanks